# react-hook-form - Controller not updating on first change

Tags: typescript, react-hook-form

This is my example
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-basic-forked-4stdl?file=/src/index.js

It has 2 input examples - firstName and lastName.
Typing a space into firstName correctly displays  an error.

Typing a space into lastName (Using a Controller) does not display the error until second keypress. It does not fire on first change.

Not sure why this is.

```js
import React, { FC } from "react";
import { useFormContext, useWatch, Controller } from "react-hook-form";

export interface Props {
  name: string;
  label?: string;
  defaultValue?: string;
}

const ControlledInput: FC<Props> = ({
  name,
  label: labelText = "",
  defaultValue = ""
}) => {
  const { register, control, errors } = useFormContext();

  const label = labelText || name;
  const value = useWatch({
    control,
    name,
    defaultValue
  });

  console.log(
    `ControlledInput() render(), name=${name}, defaultvalue="${defaultValue}", value="${value}"`
  );
  return (
    <div>
      <Controller
        control={control}
        name={name}
        defaultValue={defaultValue}
        render={(props) => {
          const errorText = errors[name]?.type;

          // console.log('#################################');
          // console.log('name = ', name);
          // console.log(`errors[${name}] = `, errors[name]);
          // console.log('type = ', type);
          // console.log('errorText =', errorText);

          return (
            <>
              <input
                name={props.name}
                defaultValue={defaultValue}
                ref={register({
                  validate: {
                    beginSpace: (value) => /^\S/.test(value)
                  }
                })}
                type={"text"}
                placeholder={label}
                aria-label={label}
                data-error={errorText !== "" && errorText}
              />
              {errorText ? (
                <span style={{ color: "white" }}>
                  {label} ERROR: {errorText}
                </span>
              ) : null}
            </>
          );
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default ControlledInput;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know why exactly, but it updates correctly on first change if you put your validating rules on the `Controller` directly in the `rules` prop instead of giving them to the `register` of the contained input.

[Here is the codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-basic-forked-kuyxu?file=/src/ControlledInput.tsx).

And here is that part of the code:

```js
      <Controller
        control={control}
        name={name}
        defaultValue={defaultValue}
        rules={{
          validate: {
            beginSpace: (value) => /^\S/.test(value)
          }
        }}
        render={(props) => {
          const errorText = errors[name]?.type;
          return (
            <>
              <input
                name={props.name}
                defaultValue={defaultValue}
                ref={register}
                type={"text"}
                placeholder={label}
                aria-label={label}
                data-error={errorText !== "" && errorText}
              />
              {errorText ? (
                <span style={{ color: "white" }}>
                  {label} ERROR: {errorText}
                </span>
              ) : null}
            </>
          );
        }}
      />
```

Comment: Yes it does fire but now remove the text and it doesn't clear the error. That is another problem with controller I am finding. It seems to not update on first change.

Comment: The same behavior happens with the normal input: if you put a space then remove it the error will stay. It's because of your regex that checks if there is at least one non-space character. You can change it to something like this to include also "nothing" as a valid value: `(value) => /(^\S)|(^$)/.test(value)`

Comment: I had the same problem and it was fixed by using rules on the controller - thanks

Comment: I had the same problem and it was fixed by using rules on the controller - thanks

Comment: I had the same problem and it was fixed by using rules on the controller - thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use `useEffect` with dependency like that:

`

```
const { errors, dirtyFields } = form.formState
useEffect(() => {
    if (
        !Object.keys(errors).length &&
        dirtyFields.password &&
        dirtyFields.account &&
        dirtyFields.full_name &&
        dirtyFields.user_name
    ) {
        setActiveButtonRegister(true);
    } else {
        setActiveButtonRegister(false);
    }
}, [dirtyFields, errors]);`
```